# Converting Tuple to Integer in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list, integer, tuples

So I have an issue that I can't find a way to turn my list into a list of integers.

```
    line = file.read() #Line is now referring to the list
    line = ast.literal_eval(line)
    a = line[0:0]
    net = line[0:1]
    netclicks = line[0:2]
```

This is part of the code which I'm using at the moment. Can anyone help (Btw Python 3.8)

Comment: Can you show some sample inputs/outputs?

Comment: A [mcve] would help.

Answer (score 0):

Could you show the contents of 'file' or otherwise what kind of list (using placeholders) you're trying to assign to 'line'? also what exactly are you trying to end up with?

If I had to guess right now I suppose you tried to get something like:

```
line = [1, 2, 3]

a = line[0]  # Returns 'int(1)'
net = line[1]  # Returns 'int(2)'
netclicks = line[2]  # Returns 'int(3)'
```

or perhaps:

```
line = [1, 2, 3]

a = [line[0]]  # Returns '[1]'
net = [line[1]]  # Returns '[2]'
netclicks = [line[2]]  # Returns '[3]'
```

I will add that I'm not to familiar with 'ast.literal_eval()', read that it's a security measure. Could it affect the contents of 'line' at all?

Comment: ([0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 15, 1.1, 0, 250, 1.12, 0, 3500, 1.14, 0, 40000, 1.16, 0, 750000, 1.18, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
That's the contents; it's basically a 3D with the input into the file being two varables.

import random
import os.path
import os
from stat import S_IREAD
from stat import S_IWUSR
import sys
import random
import ast
import functools

And that's all my imports.

Comment: Also the second one was what I was doing before I added the 2nd. Would it be more useful if I combined it all into one list?

Comment: Sorry for the late response mate. Regarding your issue I'm still not entirely sure what you're trying to end up with after executing the initial bit of code. But I did notice that you're trying to import specific parts of a separate file through indexing, The more common way would be to do something like ''var = fileName.VariableFunctionAnything". Could that be the source of the issue? And if not could you type out what output you're specifically aiming for?